# C++/CLI: Access violation when debugging/stepping into code in 32-bit (VS-2015)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, access-violation

I got this strange issue when stepping into code when debugging a 32-bit mixed mode assembly. The stripped down version of the code looks like this:

```
public ref class FooClass {
    public:
        FooClass();
};

FooClass::FooClass(){
    // Note: doesn't matter what code is in here, as long as it is native
    char test[10];
    memset((void*)test, 0, sizeof(test));
}
```

This class is then instantiated in another class:

```
FooClass^ BarClass::Test() {
    FooClass^ addr = gcnew FooClass();
    return addr;
}
```

..which again is instantiated in a C# console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BarClass bar = new BarClass();
        FooClass foo  = bar.Test();
    }
}
```

When stepping through the code, and into the FooClass constructor, I get an exception

(note: removed argument info for the sake of less mess):

```
ntdll.dll!_NtTraceEvent@16()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!EtwpEventWriteFull()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_EtwEventWrite@20()   Unknown
clrjit.dll!Compiler::lvaInitTypeRef() Line 253  C++
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompileHelper(...) Line 3489   C++
clrjit.dll!Compiler::compCompile(...) Line 3092 C++
clrjit.dll!jitNativeCode(...) Line 4063 C++
clrjit.dll!CILJit::compileMethod(...) Line 180  C++
[Managed to Native Transition]  
>   FooBar.dll!FooBar::BarClass::Test() Line 16 C++
ConsoleApp.exe!ConsoleApp.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 15   C#
```

However, if I just add breakpoints in the constructors and just run to next breakpoint, the code runs fine.

Also, when removing native code, it runs fine.

This issue does not occur in 64-bit mode. I crosschecked for settings, but can't really see anything special.

There are no 3rd party dll's, all the native code is compiled into the assembly.

This is not my first C++/CLI project, but first time I do it in VS2015.

Comment: VS2015 suffers from the static initialization order fiasco, but that's not what this looks like.  The snippets offer no repro and the stack trace no insight.  Consider Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  it needs to be turned on to successfully debug C++/CLI code.

Comment: @HansPassant, that did the trick... thanks ! I'd say this is the actual answer, could you add this ?

Comment: Well, congratulations but I have no idea whatsoever how the debugger engine could get the jitter to fail.  I got no repro for this at all so can't verify that the solution is accurate.  Feel free to add the answer yourself and flag my comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments in my original question, the following was suggested:

1. Enter Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
2. Enable the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox

This fixed the issue.

Comment: Since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer later. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: I probably will, but I'll see if anything else may come into light first.. there may be more to this :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was an exception in an internal managed component, that apparently did not propagate well to the native layer that invoked it - and manifested as exactly this impossible ETW stack.

To debug I had to attach as managed-only. The exception was staring me right in the face (missing DLL, but that's irrelevant).

Hope this helps someone out there.